# Mapping a strict vs. a lazy function

Tags: haskell, strictness, equational-reasoning

```
(head . map f) xs = (f . head) xs
```

It works for every xs list when f is strict. 
Can anyone give me example, why with non-strict f it doesnt work?

Comment: Where did you get this question?

Comment: I'm preparing for an exam and this is question that was on the previous one

Answer (score 4):

Let's take the non-strict function `f = const ()`, and `xs = undefined`. In this case, we have

```
map f undefined = undefined
```

but

```
f undefined = ()
```

and so

```
(head . map f) undefined = head (map f undefined) = head undefined = undefined
```

but

```
(f . head) undefined = f (head undefined) = f undefined = ()
```

Q.E.D.